# pycurl and MLST

Tags: ftp, pycurl

For several reasons, we would like to use `pycurl` to get information on a file stored on a FTP server with the [MLST command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659#page-23).

We get almost what we need with the following code:

```py
# More or less equivalent to: curl --list -X MLST -D /tmp/headers ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/archaea/assembly_summary.txt 
import pycurl
try:
    from io import BytesIO
except ImportError:
    from StringIO import StringIO as BytesIO
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, r'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/archaea/assembly_summary.txt')
c.setopt(pycurl.DIRLISTONLY, True)
# Use MLST
c.setopt(c.CUSTOMREQUEST, "MLST")
# Write header to buffer
output = BytesIO()
c.setopt(pycurl.HEADERFUNCTION, output.write)
# Perform request
c.perform()
# Print header
result = output.getvalue()
result = result.decode('ISO-8859-1')
```

`perform()` fails with [CURLE_FTP_COULDNT_RETR_FILE](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) but `result` (the headers) contains what we need. If you try the CLI version, the return code is also CURLE_FTP_COULDNT_RETR_FILE but the file `/tmp/headers` contains the data.

We think that is is related to the fact that `MLST` use the control connection and not the data connection.

Any idea ?

**EDIT 1**

We haven't found a way to get the result without `DIRLISTONLY` (which is weird). Also if we use `NOBODY` we don't get the answer.

**EDIT 2**

It turns out that `result` contains the information about the directory (`ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/archaea/`) not the file so the code here is **incorrect**.

Comment: You probably want to set `CURLOPT_NOBODY` + Not setting `DIRLISTONLY` can help too (you are not doing directory listing - what would involve data connection). + Doing this in native Python ftplib would be way easier and more straightforward.

Comment: We haven't found a way to get the result without `DIRLISTONLY` and using `NOBODY` didn't help (we tried that before - I will update the question).

We know how to handle that with `ftplib` but out whole software is based on `pycurl` so we would like to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is hard (if not impossible) to do (see **EDIT 2**). However a simple code allows to get the most important information (file size and last modification time).

The code is based on the [getinfo](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/curlobject.html?#pycurl.Curl.getinfo) method (and the [OPT_FILETIME](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FILETIME.html) option):

```py
import pycurl
try:
    from io import BytesIO
except ImportError:
    from StringIO import StringIO as BytesIO
import datetime
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, r'ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/archaea/assembly_summary.txt')
c.setopt(pycurl.NOBODY, True)
c.setopt(pycurl.OPT_FILETIME, True)
# Perform request
c.perform()
# Print info
timestamp = c.getinfo(pycurl.INFO_FILETIME)
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp))
print(c.getinfo(pycurl.CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD))
```

Of course, we use [NOBODY](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_NOBODY.html) to avoid downloading the file.

This is more or less equivalent to the command:

```
$ curl --head ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/archaea/assembly_summary.txt
Last-Modified: Thu, 07 Nov 2019 11:58:21 GMT
Content-Length: 1207490
Accept-ranges: bytes
```